# Page redirect in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

My site has three different logins and when I login using each different pages, it has to be the same main layout. My code is below.

```
public $components = array(
    'Session','Auth' => array(
        'redirectUrl' => array('controller'=>'login', 'action'=>'index'),

        'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'truckallocation', 'action'=>'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'home', 'action'=>'index'),
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
     if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'dealer') {
   $this>redirect(array('controller'=>'purchaseorder','action'=>'index');
   }
    }

        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password'=>'password'
                ),
                'scope' => array('User.active'=>1),
                'passwordHasher'=>'Blowfish'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This code doesn't work. What is the error?

Comment: It is confused that you say different pages and main page. May I know are you talking about layout or template?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please update your question with more details about what you are trying to achieve. Just taking a quick look at your code an obvious issue is that you've put an `if` statement in the middle of your `$components` variable which isn't valid PHP!

Comment: what do you mean by differnt pages?I think you have one login page,and login role is diffrent  like dealer seller and so on.Please mention clearly.

Comment: when i login using dealer the main page is differnt and when login using manager the page is differnt

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that if statement in array of your component init. 
You need to place that statement in your login action , after checking if user is logged in and his type redirect to necessary page